# React-Native Android build : Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am using ExpoKit to develop a react-native android build. I keep getting this error when trying to generate the apk for my project to deploy to the play store.

```
org.gradle.execution.MultipleBuildFailures: Build completed with 1 failures.
...
Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseExpoAssets'.
...
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Comment: did you try cleaning the gradle and then rebuild. Eventually, this works for me.

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work. I'm using expolkit and all the modules load except :app:bundleReleaseExpoAssets